# Arithmetic Sequence equation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In today's task i've got to implement the below equation, but im struggling with the final output.

[image]

This is what I've made so far:

```py
import math

def f(x, y):
    return ((x + y) / x)**2

summary = 0
sumw = 0

for j in range(1, 5):
    sumw = 0
    for k in range(1, 8):
        sumw += f(j, k)
    summary += sumw
print(summary)
```

OUTPUT:

```
343.97222222222223
```

but the final output is unfortunetaly 343.972223

What should I do in this case? Any ideas how to solve this one?
Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: The entire inner sum needs to be squared, not the individual terms. Move the `**2` to the second last line.

Comment: oh shoot, deffo too early for me, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code, the main problem is that the squared operator has to include the entire sum over the `k` indexes. This is the correction version:

```
summary = 2
for j in range(1, 5):
    sumw = 0
    for k in range(1, 8):
        sumw += (j+k)/j
    summary += sumw**2
print(summary)
# 2130.777777777778
```

Altenatively, you can also write a one-liner:

```
summary = 2 + sum(sum((j+k)/j for k in range(1,8))**2 for j in range(1,5))
```